# Проброс портов на разные серверы в локальной сети

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, nat

Помогите разобраться.

В наличии:

1. 2 веб-сервера с Apache на борту. Один работает на порту 80, другой на 84
2. Шлюз под управлением Ubuntu.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача:
Необходима возможность заходить как на 1 так и на 2 сервер, при обращении как извне так из локальной сети.
Делаю посредством настройки iptables.
Для одного сервера все получается, когда пытаюсь дать доступ на второй - не стартуют интерфейсы на шлюзе.
Не могу додуматься как дать доступ на второй сервер.

Что делаю:
Настройки iptables для одного сервера таковы:
Как я это понимаю - настраиваю маршрут для внешнего запроса и открываю все порты.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
*nat

-A PREROUTING --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP -p tcp  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2

-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING --dst 192.168.1.2 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1

-A OUTPUT --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2


:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [184:15331]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [192:16022]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
```

Тут уже закрадывается ощущение, что что-то неправильно. Однако все работает как извне, так и с локала.

При добавлении второго правила, что бы при запросе на определенный порт извне, запрос уходил на другой сервер и его порт, получается такая картина:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
*nat

-A PREROUTING --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP -p tcp  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
-A PREROUTING --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP -p tcp --dport 84 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:84

-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING --dst 192.168.1.2 -p tcp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
-A POSTROUTING --dst 192.168.1.3 -p tcp --dport 84 -j SNAT --to sourece 192.168.1.1

-A OUTPUT --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP  -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
-A OUTPUT --dst ВНЕШНИЙ_IP  -p tcp --dport 84 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2

:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [184:15331]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [192:16022]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Apr 28 10:40:15 2018
```

В результате при перезагрузке интерфейсов получаю в лог ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен, тому кто вправит мозги, и укажет верный путь =)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю ты используеш не тот инструмент. Поставь nginx в качестве http прокси и заведи все апачи на него. Так ты избавишся от проблем с маршрутизацией потому что все пользователи будут идти на один сервак, повысиш безопасность апачи можно отделить в DMZ и если правильно настроить можно поднять производительность.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил вопрос пока более простым (для меня) способом.

1. Ставим еще одну ubuntu после шлюза.
2. На шлюзе пробрасываем порты на эту ubuntu.
3. на этой ubuntu ставим утилиту rinetd. В конфигах rinetd указываем на какой ip уйдет запрос.
4. Работает.

Нагрузка небольшая, кол-во клиентов минимально, все довольны.